# VSTO Contacts and Phone List View

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsto, outlook-addin

I am implementing a small app where I have added a custom column IsApproved, it is a Yes/No field. It shows and works fine. Is it possible upon doing an action in the toolbar to change the color of either the checkboxes or a cell based on whether or not the Yes/No is checked? (or selected as yes) ?.

I haven't been able to find a way to change the color of the cell of the Phone List or the checkbox. Any help with information as to if it can be done or not would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you controls on a Windows Form that you created in the add-in project? By "toolbar", are you referring to a Ribbon control or the old-style Office toolbars?

Comment: yes it's a toolbar in the actual outlook, not a windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but all you need to do is trap the Click event of the RibbonCheckBox button control (you don't specify exactly what kind of control this is) and modify your other Windows Forms controls as you wish based on the value of the RibbonCheckBox.Checked property.

Comment: Oh i think i know where you are confused. I am sorry. So under Contacts, there is a view called "Phone List", I added a column there called "IsApproved", and it is a yes/no field. So for every contact i add, i can choose "IsApproved". Then on the toolbar I have a button call "Upload Approved", so when clicked it uses an API to send only the contacts that have "IsApproved" checked marked. I would like to turn the color of that specific cell (in the row) or the checkbox to another color.

Comment: Ah! My answer stands, but to control the coloring of items in the View does not require code.  You can setup a conditional formatting rule in one or more views in that folder, so when IsApproved = Yes you can set a specific font + color + size that applies to the item.  Note that you cannot set the formatting for an individual column.

Comment: Also: to make the changes to the selected Contact, you need to use Explorer.Selection to get a ContactItem object.  Assuming that IsApproved is a custom property that you've added to these contacts, you can access the value of that field via the ContactItem.UserProperties collection and set it when the user clicks your custom button (then call ContactItem.Save).

Comment: The problem is that I can't tell the user to set those conditional fomatting, I would have to program something so that when they install the add in it will already have that functionality. I will look more closely on your suggestion of the contact item :).